# Align Android GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I need that the GridLayout align the views like this (the light blue icons and text are the view in the GridLayout):

[image]

But my GridLayout align like this:
[image]

And if I set `app:layout_columnWeight="1"` `and app:layout_rowWeight="1"`, my GridLayout align like this:
[image]

My GridLayout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            app:columnCount="7">

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Trilha"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Mergulho"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Praia"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Festas"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Parque de Diversões"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Relaxar"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Esportes Radicais"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Acampamento"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Off Road"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Passeio de Barco"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Restaurantes"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Show / Festival"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Resort / SPA"/>

            <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.KeywordView
                android:id="@+id/keyword14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                keyword:text="Locas Históricos"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

And the views inside GridView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.DefaultTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/keywordTextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Keyword"
        android:textColor="#839EC5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/keyword_button"
        android:id="@+id/keywordButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's a custom view, but now, it do nothing, only show a custom textview and a imageview... What I do to GridLayout align like the first image?

**UPDATE:**

It's near to solve my question... I change some things, and now only a view is not aligned.

[image]

I put `app:layout_columnWeight="1"` on all views of gridlayout, and changed the gravity and text width of custom view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <com.motivapp.motivapp.customview.DefaultTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/keywordTextView"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Keyword"
        android:textColor="#839EC5"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/keyword_button"
        android:id="@+id/keywordButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to center all this views? How to prevent that when textview have a big width and line break, he force the imageview go down and don't center align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom GridView with `android:numColumns="7"` or you can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager with 7 columns
You can use your custom layout for item view to define your text and image as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGridItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgGridItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This solution will work only for one screen size. Try it with a screen that has room for only 6 icons and the edge columns will be clipped. I don't know if there is a proper solution...

Comment: Have you used recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager or have you used GridView?

Answer (score 1):

this is occur because of the textview size is long thats why it take more space so kindly set width to match_parent in  your 
textview if its not worked than reduce that text size.

Comment: match_parent don't work, but if I set a text width, the text break line and force the imageview go down, then the image view force the another view to go down too... How to centralize (with line breaks) like on the first image?

Comment: try ellipsize in textview

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. This assumes that you want the GridView centered in the parent. If it needs to be centered relative to something else, you will have to modify the code.

All I did was subclass onLayout and "translate" the grid view to a centered position.

```
public class GridViewCentering extends GridView
{
  public GridViewCentering (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super (context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
  {
    super.onLayout (changed, l, t, r, b);
    int parentW = ((ViewGroup)getParent ()).getMeasuredWidth();
    int w = getWidth ();
    int offset = (parentW - w) / 2;
    setTranslationX (offset);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that the views are not the same height when the text has one line or two.
There are multiple possible solutions:

Best might be:
Add ***layout_gravity="bottom"*** to each item inside the Gridlayout. If there is a view with two lines the spacing of the other views is added on top and the image (circle) is all at the same height.

If you want all rows to have the same height you could add ***android:minLines="2"*** to all the Textviews. But this would put a spacing between the text and the image for short texts.

Answer (score 0):

Use **RecyclerView** instead of **GridLayout** and set count to 7.

Comment: I can't use adapters, listview, recyclerview... I need to use this layout witouth any adapter

Comment: try changing 

app:columnCount="7"

to:

android:columnCount="7"

Comment: 'app' namespace because I using support GridLayout (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout), if I change to the normal GridLayout and use the 'android' namescape, it does not change the result

Answer (score 0):

Use this in xml

```
<GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Comment: It's a gridlayout, not a gridview, don't have stretchMode

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager like this

`GridLayoutManager  mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);`

Set layout manager to adapter
`mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);`

Comment: I can't use adapter, it realy need to be only a gridlayout with 'fixed' views, not adapters